# Add an image as a background to a previously manipulated image with Imagemagick

Tags: image, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I'm writing a script that:

- Scales
- Crops
- Adds a background image

to a series of around 400 transparent PNGs.  I'd like to make this run as fast as possible.

Currently I've got it as two separate commands:

```
convert $input.png -scale $scale% -gravity Center -crop 640x640+0+0 +repage $output.png
composite -gravity center $output.png $background $output.png
```

Is there a way to reduce this to a single command?  I've been looking at the docs for -composite but I can't see a way to add an image as the background **after** doing the other manipulation.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a && between the two commands? The second command will get executed when the furst exits without an error... Should work...

Comment: That will stil execute as two commands though right?  So will it make any difference to the speed of execution?  Maybe by not having to write the image file between commands.

Comment: Yes, they are still two commands, but the second gets only executed, when the first one finished successfully. I don't think it is possible to do both steps by one command, but maybe there are some imagemagick gurus outside with more experience...